# How to distribute my Python script to other computers without python?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have this Python script which I want to run on other windows computers without python.So i have tried py2exe and pyinstaller but none of these work as when I try copy the .exe file to an other system and run it but I get an ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.pyw", line 4, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "gtk\__init__.pyo", line 30, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "gobject\__init__.pyo", line 26, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "glib\__init__.pyo", line 22, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading glib\_glib.pyd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) or include Python installing to program installer (may be a batch script):

`msiexec /i /quiet /passive python.msi`

Answer (score 0):

When needing to make an executable out of a Python script, I found [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (or its GUI brother [GUI2Exe](https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/) to be the most useful tools. There are a few [other options](http://tinyurl.com/pxntk4p).